# I can't figure it out the animation is not working

Tags: html, css

The background appears but after 5 seconds authorization appears

first the circle will appear smoothly and slowly, then the authorization window should appear in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16j4MkPrI1Y&t=1s

searched all over the internet and couldn't find anything

Maybe I forgot the form somewhere, please help

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

input {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #385983;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #E9F2FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #C1D9FD;
}

main {
  background: #F1F5FE;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 2534px;
  height: 2534px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F7FAFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 70px 6px rgba(217, 229, 255, 0.25);
  animation-name: fadeCircle;
  animation-direction: .7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeCircle {
  0% {
    width: 2534px;
    height: 2534px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1500px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 534px;
    height: 534px;
  }
}

.register-form-container {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 415px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px rgba(217, 229, 225, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 38px;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
  animation-name: fadeForm;
  animation-direction: .7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeForm {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: .25;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: .75;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.form-title {
  color: #30507D;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.form-field {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  background: #247FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #0D6CF2;
}

a.button {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-google {
  color: #C6CFDC;
  background: #F2F6FF;
}

.button-google:hover {
  background: #E2E6F0;
  color: #fff
}

.divider {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #405D87;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>book.py</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="register-form-container">
      <h1 class="form-title">
        Регистрация
      </h1>
      <div class="form-flield">
        <div class="form-flield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
        </div>
        <div class="form-flield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Почта">
        </div>
        <div class="form-flield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
        <div class="form-flield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Подтвердить Пароль">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-buttons">
        <buttton class="button">Регистрация</buttton>
        <div class="divider">или</div>
        <a href="#" class="button button-google">Google</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _animation-direction: .7s;_?

Comment: Your formCircle animation refers to an empty div. Your .form-field css has no use in the html, because your fields have the class .form-flield. Your formFade animation is not referenced anywhere in your html.